# How to salvage questions which are off topic but elicit on topic answers?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

A question seemingly about repair of stuff, [Add ground earth to a Chinese music player](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/244414/add-ground-earth-to-a-chinese-music-player/),  elicited answers touching topics like

- general device design
- regulatory information
- safety advice
- circut reengineering

and so on. In fact no answer contained a repair advice (of course). But I think some of the answers are worth being saved. But we can't throw away the question without losing the answers or at least the context.

Should we seriously reconstruct the question to remove any sign of a repair question?

Answer (score 2):

Answering a bad question is itself bad, regardless of how good the answer may be.  Bad questions need to be dealt with properly, which includes the OP not getting the desired result.  This decreases the chance of him doing the same thing again, and serves notice to bystanders that bad questions don't work.

I have previously suggested that all questions to answers that end up getting closed due to other than *duplicate* reason should get -5 rep regardless of votes.  The point is to discourage users from answering bad questions.

You did exactly what we don't want you to do, and now you don't like the result.  Good.  You got what you deserved.  Actually, you got way more than you deserved.  You got +70 rep, whereas in my system you would have gotten -5.
I note that the question as it stands now isn't so bad, but it was when you answered it.  You should have known better.

However, to actually answer your question, yes, there is something you can do.  In the SE system it is acceptable to ask a question and then answer it yourself.  You can even do this before anyone else has a chance to see the question.  You could ask a targeted and well-written question, then copy your existing answer to it.  This is not something you should do lightly or often.  Personally I wouldn't bother for a relatively short answer as yours.  It couldn't have taken that much effort to write.

Also keep in mind that the answer will stay where it is and will still be findable with searches.  If I remember right, closed questions with upvoted answers won't get automatically deleted.  So you don't really need to do anything.  The highly edited question and your answer will stay here as part of the repository of information this site is trying to build.

Comment: Then for educational purposes I should delete my answer, shouldn't I?

Comment: @Ariser: No, the OP has already gotten what he wanted.  At this point the answer is part of the repository, and should remain.  Besides, deleting it for "educational purposes" makes no sense.

Comment: I get your point and will probably look more carefully, if a Q is on-topic, before posting an answer. I'm aware of the Q&A-style as I already used it once. Nevertheless I couldn't have used it in this case because I wasn't aware there are electrocutors with an background music option on the market.

Answer (score -2):

The question has great answers and is independently good, considering it has no down votes at all. It was closed by a bunch of low rep users, one who double dipped to leave it close in reopen review queue after having closed it themselves. While they may not have all chosen it as off-topic for the same reason (only a mod can see that, maybe), the system displays the reason with the most votes, even if it is just 2, and attributes it to everyone that voted to close. It is not really a repair question, as a modification question, and goes into theory. People just like to b***h and be pedantic about the rules. ***Can't see the forest for the trees.*** The rule is in place to stop "Uh, this thing broke, how can i fix?" questions, not highly detailed analysis questions.

### That said, all that can be done is to edit and vote to reopen. If enough people do that, it will get reopen.

The other option is to flag for a **Historical Lock**, which would simply be a change in the close reason from off-topic, to "useful but we don't want new questions of the same type".

### Secondly, even though it is closed, due to it's high up-voting, it shouldn't get deleted automatically.

Comment: This question was off-topic. The fact the manufacturer decided to screw with safety rules this bad makes it anecdotally more interesting than the average off-topic question (and that is why it got upvotes), but it doesn't make it on-topic. Moreover, the amount of reputation of the users voting to close is irrelevant. Some of them (I'm not including myself here) do a very good job in the review queues and in cleaning up this site, which is not rewarded by rep, indeed. So you should thank them to do this dirty job instead of belittling them.